# Android service run timer even if user leaves the app (destroy it)

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

I'm creating an application where the user presses the button and then I start the service with `CountDownTimer`. When the timer stops I create notification. Everything works perfect when app is running, however when user closes the app I don't get any notification. I fix that by removing `unregisterReceiver` on `onPause` and `onStop`. But when the user destroys the app (completely removes app from background) I don't get any notification at all. How to continue service even if the app is destroyed? 
Here's my service

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "your_package_name.countdown_br";
    private Intent intent = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        long time = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);
        Log.d("SDKJDSDSDSDSDSDSD", time + "");
        startCount(time);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void startCount(long time){
        Log.d("SDIUSDSDSD", time + "");
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                intent.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                intent.putExtra("countdown", -1);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        };

        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here how I start my service
My StartTimerActivirt class

```
public class DetailChargeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{
    private Button startCharge, startReserveButton;
    private int selectedYear = -1, selectedMonth = -1, selectedDay = -1;
    private int startH = -1, startMin = -1, endH = -1, endMin = -1;
    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean chronometerStarted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_charge);

        //.... set up listeners and so on...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startTimer(0, 2);
    }


    private void startTimer(int startH, int startMin){
        long time = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(startH * 60 + startMin);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
        intent.putExtra("time", time);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(TimerService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       // unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
          //  unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, TimerService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            Log.d("DSDafsdfdfKSD", "SASASASSASAS " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            if(millisUntilFinished == 0) {
                buildNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildNotification(){
        Log.d("DSDafsdfdfKSD", "ASASSA");
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cast_dark)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understood it well, you can set time in Android Notification . you don't need timer for notification

Comment: I need timer because when timer ends only then I show notification. It acts like a remainder that timer ends.

Comment: Although this looks like a very duplicated question, I'll tell you a pair of things. First, I think this is not a good pattern, and Android usability guides doesn't recommend it in most cases. Maybe you should try with ForegroundService, check if it's what you need

Comment: @Hugo Thanks I will definitely look for it

Answer (score 0):

Return `return START_STICKY;` in `onStartCommand()` so it start the service asap if destroyed by user.

Save the remain time in on every `onTick` by detecting it. Read the comment

Service will restarted with remaining time if destoryed anyhow.

```
 public class TimerService extends Service {
        private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

        public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "your_package_name.countdown_br";
        private Intent intent = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);
        SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
        // here is prefs key
        String Key = "TIME";

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            long time = 0;
            mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (mPrefs.getLong(Key, 0) == 0) {
                time = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);
                mPrefs.edit().putLong(Key, time).apply();
            } else {
                time = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);
            }
            // now start the counter
            Log.d("SDKJDSDSDSDSDSDSD", time + "");
            startCount(time);
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        private void startCount(long time) {
            Log.d("SDIUSDSDSD", time + "");
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long remainingTime = mPrefs.getLong(Key, 0) - millisUntilFinished;
                    mPrefs.edit().putLong(Key, remainingTime).apply();
                    intent.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    intent.putExtra("countdown", -1);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            };
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```